# Under which conditions: dim(W1 + W2 + W3) = dim(W1) + dim(W2) + dim(W3) − dim(W1 ∩ W2) − dim(W2 ∩ W3) − dim(W3 ∩ W1) + dim(W1 ∩ W2 ∩ W3)

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $K$, and let $W_1$, $W_2$ and $W_3$ be subspaces of $V$. By analogy with the inclusion-exclusion principle for sets, and taking into account the dimension formula for a sum of 2 subspaces, we can ask whether the following equality holds:

$$\dim(W_1 + W_2 + W_3) = \dim(W_1) + \dim(W_2) + \dim(W_3) − \dim(W_1 \cap W_2) − \dim(W_2 \cap W_3) − \dim(W_3 \cap W_1) + \dim(W_1 \cap W_2 \cap W_3)$$ (†) **it is false for the sum of 3 subspaces.**

This formula does not always hold: for example take three distinct lines in $\mathbb R^2$ as $U$, $V$, $W$. All intersections have 0 dimensions. The LHS is $2$, the RHS is $3$.

I would like to state general assumptions on the subspaces of $W_1$, $W_2$, $W_3$ which guarantee that the formula **does hold and prove it under these assumptions.**

But for which triples of (finite-dimensional) subspaces does this hold? Do you have any reference for reading? I studied a few books but could not seem to find anything. To sum up, my question I am trying to prove that the formula is True even though it is False.

Many thanks

Comment: I have checked comments to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics/23501#23501) in the famous question "[Examples of common false beliefs in mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/q/23478)". I did not notice a comment mentioning something with sufficient condition - but I might have missed something, you might want to check for yourself.  There is a question on [math.se] with no answer: [Dimension formula for Sum of Subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1506920).

Comment: You can find also some posts on [math.se] where a different formula was suggested, such as: [Dimension of the sum of subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/102579) and [The dimension of the sum of subspaces $(U_1,\ldots,U_n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/520910) And there is also this related post on [mathoverflow.se]: [Is there a version of inclusion/exclusion for vector spaces?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/17740)

Comment: Would you reformulate your post avoiding saying that a (false) formula is true and then saying that it's false? You could go straight to the point asking for which triples of (finite-dimensional) subspaces this holds, and then discuss/motivate the question.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you for your sources. However, I would like to explore an assumption to prove this. (even if the formula does not always hold).

Comment: @YCor Thanks for that I tried to re-form my question to be more understandable.

Comment: Edited your title in order to follow you following the contributions ... and +1

Comment: Just for fun: you can have a look at Tilman's answer 
[there](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478) 
and the comments.

Comment: A corresponding post on [math.se]: [Under which conditions: dim(W1 + W2 + W3) = dim(W1) + dim(W2) + dim(W3) − dim(W1 ∩ W2) − dim(W2 ∩ W3) − dim(W3 ∩ W1) + dim(W1 ∩ W2 ∩ W3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4311243)

Comment: One possible answer would be: If there is a basis such that each $W_i$ is generated by a subset of this basis then the formula holds.

Comment: @FriedrichKnop Very good (+1) ! In an equivalent manner, it means that there is an atomic decomposition s.t. every $W_i$ is direct sum of (some of these) atoms.

Comment: I think you can answer this question in the spirit of indecomposable representations of quivers/posets. Any datum $(V; W_1, W_2, W_3)$ of three subspaces $W_i$ of a f.d. vector space $V$ is isomorphic to the sum of five indecomposable things: $(K;0,0,0)$, $(K; K, 0, 0)$, $(K; 0, K, 0)$, $(K; 0, 0, K)$ and $(K^2; K(1,0), K(0,1), K(1,1))$. Your formula holds if and only your datum doesn't contain the last indecomposable example.

Comment: I have rolled back the yesterday’s anonymous suggested edit that claimed to “improved formatting and spelling”, but in reality just deleted two paragraphs that are setting the context for the question.

Answer (score 12):

The idea of PseudoNeo's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408972/under-which-conditions-dimw1-w2-w3-dimw1-dimw2-dimw3-%e2%88%92-dimw1#comment1049113_408972) settles the converse of [my statement](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408972/under-which-conditions-dimw1-w2-w3-dimw1-dimw2-dimw3-%e2%88%92-dimw1#comment1049110_408972) modulo that he missed four cases.

According to the theory of indecomposable modules of the Dynkin quiver $D_4$ with all arrows pointing to the central node there are $12$ cases corresponding to the $12$ positive roots of the Lie algebra of type $D_4$. These cases for $(V;W_1,W_2,W_3)$ are

1. $(0;K,0,0), (0;0,K,0), (0;0,0,K)$,
2. $(K;0,0,0), (K;K,0,0), (K;0,K,0), (K;0,0,K), (K;K,K,0), (K;K,0,K),(K;0,K,K),(K;K,K,K)$
3. $(K^2,K,K,K)$

All maps $W_i\to V$ in the first group are not injective. So, they are irrelevant. The second group consists precisely of those cases, where there is a basis of $V$ such that all $W_i$ are spanned by a subset of the basis.
The last is case is causing the problems. In this case the difference $\mathrm{LHS}-\mathrm{RHS}=-1$. So we arrive at the following statement:

In the formula, one always has $\mathrm{LHS}\le \mathrm{RHS}$ with equality if and only if $V$ has a basis such that all $W_i$ are spanned by a subset of that basis.

Comment: This line of thinking was also outlined in @VladimirDotsenko's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/26740) to [Is there a version of inclusion/exclusion for vector spaces?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17740).

Comment: Thanks. That is correct. I forgot to say that this line of thinking is a beautiful theorem of Gabriel. A nice exposition is contained in the blog post https://blogs.ams.org/visualinsight/2016/01/01/free-modular-lattice-on-3-generators/ by John Baez.